# "error while loading shared libraries: "libopencv_core.so"" output when running a cross-compiled program transplanted to ARM

Tags: qt, opencv

When I am on the Ubuntu server cross-compiled Qt program, the compiled project produces no error. But the cross-compiled program transplanted to ARM does.

The file is mentioned in the error, I have copied it from Ubuntu to ARM.

[image: Error in console]

I added the file path as an environment variable in `etc/profile`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Do you use opencv?

Comment: yes ，I am using opens and porting a program I cross-compiled on Ubuntu to an arm board

Comment: When you cross compile, the host machine must know about libraries for traget machine. When usnig CMake this info specifies in a toolchain file. You can read more [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/book/mastering-cmake/chapter/Cross%20Compiling%20With%20CMake.html)

Comment: `pip install python-opencv` will install all libraries. Then run script.